# How to forward a jms message from one managed server (Weblogic) to another based on some selectors without using JMS Bridges?

Tags: jms, weblogic11g, ejb-2.x

I have a application in which I need to route my JMS messages to different managed servers based on some selector value. But I cannot use JMS bridges for the purpose as the application has more than 20 managed servers in production.so with the JMS bridge approach, it will become a hurdle for the deployment team to do such huge configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You could try to use the Mule ESB or other ESB approach. I recommend the Mule ESB because it's simple, well documented and pretty lightweight.

Comment: Can I use OSB (Oracle Service Bus) for this ?

Comment: I believe you can. I recommended a mule because it is free (community version of course) :)